# Should 'cursor' property be defined in '.class' or '.class:hover'?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Since both of the following have the same effect:

```
.class {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.class:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Regarding best practices, which one should you use and why?

Comment: Regarding the close votes about the question being opinion based, yes it is at the moment, but it shouldn't be, there should be official documentation on when to use the cursor

Comment: I agree. No one knew that this was "primarily opinion-based" before the answers actually said it was. I was rather voting for this being a duplicate, as @George pointed out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two selectors are for *distinctly separate purposes*, despite the fact that- at least in practice they *appear* to accomplish the same thing.

I would tend to say it would be ***best practice*** to define the hover state using `:hover` (at least on non-touchscreen devices, see below), because:

1. It makes finding and understanding your styling more apparent in larger blocks of  CSS
2. It utilizes a specifically designated selector (which may be extended in the spec at a later date, what would then happen to your functionality?)
3. If you later add to the default styling for `.class` your states are clearly separated appropriately
4. What happens if you hand over responsibility of your CSS to another individual? Having `:hover` specific functionality defined under the correct selector makes understanding code a heck of a lot easier.
5. If you have more complex CSS its likely you'll be using `:hover` elsewhere, so should use it for the purposes of consistency
6. The two selectors represent the same element but in *different states*, semantically you should use `:hover`

**But hang on a minute..** you may notice that if you set the cursor style for an `a` element to `default` then the usual hand icon wont appear on hover...this indicates that there is baked-in prior evidence for not specifically styling `:hover` states ([**see this in action here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cUW7/9/))

In summary, there is no game breaking reason not to use simply `.class` in some circumstances- it certainly uses less bytes and if you have a fairly simple setup then only under development by you...then why not, but be wary it is probably best avoided if you want to adhere to the strict rules and better support ongoing development.

In addition..lets not forget **touchscreen devices** [MDN makes an important point here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover)

> on touch screens :hover is problematic or impossible. The :hover
>   pseudo-class never matches, or matches for a short moment after
>   touching an element. As touchscreen devices are very common, it is
>   important for web developer not to have content accessible only when
>   hovering over it, as this content would be hidden for users of such
>   devices.

As such depending on your requirement, it may *not* be best to use `:hover` as if you have it in your CSS for a touch screen device it may bake in reliance on unsupported or flakey functionality.

Comment: Most touch-based devices don't employ a pointer anyway which would make your last point essentially be "it doesn't matter for touch devices", but I'm actually curious to know what happens on devices that have *both* touch and pointer interfaces, such as Windows tablets. I don't have one handy, but it'd be interesting to know if tapping on an element will move the cursor to that element and trigger its `:hover`, or if it will ignore the `:hover` if it detects that the cursor was put there by a touch gesture and not the mouse, or if it simply doesn't move the cursor.

Comment: The closest to "baked-in prior evidence" that I can think of is that every user agent stylesheet I'm aware of specifies the `cursor` property without the `:hover` pseudo-class. For example, Firefox specifies it for `*|*:-moz-any-link` and Chrome specifies it for `a:-webkit-any-link`. But these are UA styles after all - having `:hover` in there probably wouldn't make a difference as an author-level `a` rule would still take precedence.

Comment: @BoltClock - good points, I definitely agree with #1 in that a test on an appropriate device would be interesting

Answer (score 1):

IE6 and lower only recognises the `:hover` pseudo class on `a` tags. `:hover` on a `div` or other tag will not be interpreted by those browsers.

If compatibility is a consideration, use the `:hover` else I believe there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

First, for your "same effect", it depends on what do you apply to.
Because some elements by default have "cursor: pointer" property such as

> anchor tag

While the following elements by default have "cursor: default"(no pointer)

> input type: submit

Take stackoverflow.com "Post your answer" as an example, it is a submit button with "cursor:default" by default, user's perception might think a clickable object is displaying "pointer", so it is styled with "cursor:pointer"

As a quick conclusion with my experience, there is no best practice, but rather, depends on the purpose. For clickable object but it is not display as "pointer" by default, you may style them with "pointer".
When you disabled something, eg when you activate something then enable an anchor link, you may use something like

```
/* the a is only for illustrative purpose */
a.disabled{
   cursor: default;
}

a.enabled{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Because cursor is a matter of visual presentation, related to user experience design(UX).

Comment: This is not answering the question, but rather informing about why to use the `cursor` property at all.

Comment: But the question, isn't that "when to use it"? It is just my experience of when to use it. What is the problem?

Comment: The question is rather "Whether to use :hover psuedo-class or not"

Comment: I see your point, because I just follow his title "CSS cursor property, when to use it". That's what I intended to answer. Thanks for your opinion.