# Should I use the :hover pseudo-class in combination with the cursor CSS property?

Tags: css

In CSS the cursor property sets the mouse cursor to show when the mouse pointer is over (hover) an element. So technically it should only affect `:hover` events even if it's not used in combination (`cursor`).

I know SO doesn't allow opinion-based questions, but are there technical reasons to use one of the options below over the other:
**Option 1:**

```
.card {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I would like to write my code in the best way possible and avoid hidden caveats.

Comment: Since you are applying style for cursor, there is no point in using `:hover`, unless you somehow _want_ to style your cursor when it's not hovering element (is it even possible?)

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504437/should-cursor-property-be-defined-in-class-or-classhover?rq=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTML spec, it's actually possible to [match an element's `:hover` without hovering over it using *labelable elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#concept-selector-hover:%7E:text=Additionally%2C%20any%20element%20that%20is%20the%20labeled%20control%20of%20a%20label%20element%20that%20is%20currently%20matching%20%3Ahover%2C%20also%20matches%20%3Ahover.%20(But%2C%20it%20does%20not%20count%20as%20being%20designated.)). **However**, [the CSS spec for `cursor`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#cursor:%7E:text=This%20property%20specifies%20the%20type%20of%20cursor%20to%20be%20displayed%20for%20the%20pointing%20device%20when%20the%20cursor%E2%80%99s%20hotspot%20is%20within%20the%20element%E2%80%99s%20border%20edge.) explicitly states that the custom cursor should only be displayed if the pointing device is within the element's border edge, meaning the user agent should always perform hit testing before applying the cursor.

In other words, for the `cursor` property, it doesn't matter because it is guaranteed to only activate when the cursor is hovering over the element's bounding box. So you might as well minimize your code and just use the `.card` selector.